# Parsing XML using simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, xml

Using `simplexml_load_file(),` if I'm parsing out XML and I get the following for image...

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [size] => small
        )
    [0] => http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/72903330.png
)

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [size] => medium
        )
    [0] => http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/72903330.png
) // ... etc
```

My question is...how do I get to the image URL at array[0]?  I know how to access my 'size' attribute with the `attributes()` method. But I can't seem to echo out the URL. I've tried

```
$img = $xml -> album -> image[0];  <----i see nothing
$img = $xml -> album -> image -> 0;   <-----i get a 500 error
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
-Bob

Comment: Can you provide a portion of the XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(string) $xml->album->image;
```

or

```
(string) $xml->album->image[0];
```

Should do the trick.

You could also try

```
$xml->album->image->asXML();
```